# Adding parse framework prevents pch file precompile

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, parse-platform, pch

I have an iOS project in Xcode 5.  I want to use parse in the project.

1. Compile project, everything is ok
2. Add Parse framework
3. Compile project, pch precompile fails.  Errors indicate the
   pch files imports are being compiled as C instead of ObjC
4. Remove Parse framework, do a 'clean'.
5. Compile project, pch precompile still fails.

Here is the pch file content, unchanged from default set by Xcode when generating a project:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif
```

Any ideas!?

Comment: I think this might have to do with needing the Facebook SDK + Parse

Answer (score 0):

There are other frameworks that must be included to use Parse.

They are:

```
AudioToolbox.framework
CFNetwork.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
CoreLocation.framework
libz.dylib
MobileCoreServices.framework
QuartzCore.framework
Security.framework
StoreKit.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
```

Not including these will make your application crash.